# How to label the percentage of different attributes

Tags: qgis, labeling

Using QGIS version: 3.28 LTR, in a layer with point geometry containing the field named "TYPE" and the attributes 'Normal' and 'Special', I am trying to develop an expression that allows me to label the calculation of the percentage of each different attribute in the collect centroid of each type. I show a screenshot with the expected result.

[image]

At the moment, I have partly managed to approach the solution using the following expressions in the label options, that can be seen in the second screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, for the moment with the following expression I manage to count the total number of only one attribute type, but I would like to substitute it by the percentage and add all attribute types:

```
CASE
WHEN "TYPE" = 'Special'
THEN 
count('Special',$geometry)
END
```

The Placement of the label I solve it with the following expression in the geometry generator:

```
convex_hull(collect($geometry,filter:="TYPE"='Special'))
```

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: QGIS version: 3.28 LTR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be achieved by aggregating the various values into arrays (using filters to choose the attribute value), then finding the length of those arrays.

```sql
-- this case statement is to ensure the label is rendered only once per group (else it is rendered for every feature)
case when $id = array_min(array_agg($id, group_by:="TYPE"))
then
-- get total count
with_variable(
    'total',
    array_length(
        array_agg($id)
    ),
    
    -- count how many instances of "Normal"
    with_variable(
        'normal',
        array_length(
            array_agg(
                "TYPE",
                filter:="TYPE"='Normal'
            )
        ),
        -- count how many instances of "Special"
        with_variable(
            'special',
            array_length(
                array_agg(
                    "TYPE",
                    filter:="TYPE"='Special'
                )
            ),

             -- generate the label string based on the value of "TYPE" ( || is the concatenator operator, the @ symbol is to call the variables that were created above)
             case 
                when "TYPE" = 'Normal'
                then 'Normal: '  || @normal  || ' (' || to_string(@normal / @total * 100) || '%)'
                when "TYPE" = 'Special'
                then 'Special: ' || @special || ' (' || to_string(@special / @total * 100) || '%)'
             end
                
        )
    )
)
end
```

The adapted placement expression:

```sql
case 
    when "TYPE" = 'Special'
    then
        point_on_surface(
            convex_hull(collect($geometry,filter:="TYPE"='Special'))
        )
    when "TYPE" = 'Normal'
    then 
        point_on_surface(
            convex_hull(collect($geometry,filter:="TYPE"='Normal'))
        )
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Matt.
In relation to Placement, is it possible to differentiate the location for each type of attribute? That is, the point_on _surface is identified for each different attribute.

Comment: It was a reasonably simple change. Just adding a case statement to both the label expression and the placement expression. You may need to experiment with the placement so that the the `"Normal"` label doesn't sit over the `"Special"` convex hull.

Comment: Sorry, I  forgot to change the first line, the aggregation in the very first `case` statement needs a `group_by` parameter. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry. The effect I was looking for with the point_on_surface placement function is not quite convincing. Is it possible to group the labels a x,y position and delimit them with \n ?

Comment: You could try your original placement expression,  without the `point_on_surface` function. Or various other ways of placing them. If that doesn't work, you can look at the edit history of my answer to get the first expression that makes the label in one location :)